# Javascript createElement and append child node

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an element and append a child node to it, but my return is just a string without the element.

I'm first creating the element with

`const li = document.createElement('li');`

Secondly, I'm creating the text node with:

`const text = document.createTextNode('hello');`

Finally I'm appending the text to the li with:

`const newMessage = li.appendChild(text);`

Results for `console.log(newMessage)` is just a string of the message. Output in the dom is just a string also. I'm expecting the complete `li` element with the text node. I've also tried using innerHTML instead of appendChild.

Seems like a huge noob question but I'm not sure what I'm missing?

Thanks,

Comment: `appendChild` returns the appended node (here, `text`; `text === newMessage` here, which doesn't make much sense). Try logging `li` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append the `li` element to the `dom` too, to show it.

```js
const li = document.createElement('li');
const text = document.createTextNode('hello');
var a=li.appendChild(text);
document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li)
console.log(a)
```

```html
<ul id="list">
</ul>
```

Comment: Ahhh of course. such a stupid moment! I'll accept the answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

[Node.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild#Returns)

***Return value***

> The returned value is the appended child except when the given child is a [*DocumentFragment*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment), in which case the empty [*DocumentFragment*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) is returned.

You do not need to assign the `li.appendChild` in a variable:

```js
const li = document.createElement('li');
const text = document.createTextNode('hello');
li.appendChild(text);
console.log(li.appendChild(text).nodeName); // #text
document.querySelector('ul').appendChild(li);
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to append your `li` into the DOM for it to appear. You can do it by querying a parent element and using `appendChild` on it:

```
document.querySelector('ul').appendChild(li);
```

The `appendChild` function returns the node that was just appended. In your case, `newMessage` will be the text node appended to your `li`, see [the MDN appendChild doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

```js
const li = document.createElement('li');
const text = document.createTextNode('hello');
const newMessage = li.appendChild(text);

document.querySelector('ul').appendChild(li);

console.log(newMessage);
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```